# How can I send the button ID from onClick to handleClick in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so here is what i'm trying to do. I have 3 buttons in material ui and I gave each one of them and id. I want to send the id through a onClick to a single handleclick function that then runs a switch case and determines which button pressed the id and then sets the state accordingly. This is because I want to have so when a button is clicked, it sets a key value that i specifiy depending on which one what clicked. Here is my code below

```
const [key, setKey] = useState("");

    const  handleClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const target = e.target as Element;
    const id = target.id;
    alert(id);
  };

  async function register(e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const registerData = {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        username,
        password,
        passwordVerify: passwordConfirm,
        key: { key },
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
<Button
  id="btn1"
  className={classes.buttonStyle}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  Student
</Button>
<Button
  id="btn2"
  className={classes.buttonStyle}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  {" "}
  Ta{" "}
</Button>
<Button
  id="btn3"
  className={classes.buttonStyle}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  {" "}
  Admin{" "}
</Button>
```

My problem is that whenever I click the button on the react page, it shows an empty alert sometimes and other times it shows up with the button. Idk why that's the case. the alert is to test if i'm actually getting an id from the button press.

can someone tell me the types I need to be adding for this to work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as follows. The correct event triggered is a `mouseEvent`.

You can access Id with `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';

...

const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  const id = e.currentTarget.id;
  console.log(id);
}

...

<Button 
  ...
  onClick={handleClick}
/>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Event type to `MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>`

```js
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'
// ... some code
const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  const id = e.currentTarget.id;
  console.log(id);
}
```

Further, for a small performance gain, it is better to declare handleClick using `useCallback`

```js
import { useCallback, MouseEvent } from 'react'
// ... more code
const handleClick = useCallback((e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  const id = e.currentTarget.id;
  console.log(id);
}, []);
```

Edit: modify answer after question edits.

Comment: thanks man. I did all of this but now my issues is that in my test alert that I made to see if i'm actually getting the correct id, I end up getting a empty alert most of the time and sometimes I get the wrong button id. know why that happens. I changed the code above accordingly and when I implemented useCallback. I only get empty alerts now

Comment: See if changing `target` to `currentTarget` helps you. It should actually.

Comment: @AmrShawki Can you see this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-satoshi-fcrzu?file=/src/App.tsx
It works when I use `currentTarget`

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. CurrentTarget worked for me along with removing the setTarget line thanks

Answer (score 0):

so I was getting an empty alert because of the setKey line. Once I removed it, the alert showed the right key (along with changing target to currentTarget. Thanks everyone for the help